# How to append the content of arrays to a std::vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++17, stdvector

I have two arrays

```
float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
};  

float normals[] = {
    0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

I first want to add the `vertices` array to a `std::vector<float>` and after that insert the `normals` array to the vector.

What I can think of is running a loop based on the `sizeof(Array)` and push back individual element to the vector.

Would that guarantee that the values inserted are in the correct sequence when I access them back?

Comment: The answer to your last question is **YES**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) the elements in the end of the vector.

```
#include <iterator> // std::cbegin, std::cend, std::size
#include <vector>
std::vector<float> vec;
// reserve the memory for unwated reallocations.
vec.reserve(std::size(vertices) + std::size(normals));

vec.insert(vec.end(), std::cbegin(vertices), std::cend(vertices));
vec.insert(vec.end(), std::cbegin(normals), std::cend(normals));
```

---

> [...] running a loop based on the `sizeof(Array)` and push back
>   individual element to the vector. Would that guarantee that the values
>   inserted are in the correct sequence when I access them back?

Yes, indeed. Remember you can use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to find the size of the array, if you have access to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or later compiler.

Comment: It is also possible to construct `vec` initially using `vertices`, and then use `insert()` to add elements of `normals`.   The cost is (potentially) an additional reallocation.

Comment: That doesn't prevent additional reallocation.   That just causes `reserve()`  to do that additional reallocation, if it is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to *append* those two arrays to an **existing** `std::vector` or **create a new** one out of them. In both cases, you very likely want to reserve all the memory needed for the insertions in one go to avoid additional unnecessary reallocations.

For the former case, you can use the following function template:

```
template<size_t... Ns>
void append_to_vector(std::vector<float>& vec, float (&...arrs)[Ns]) {
   constexpr auto num_elements_to_append = sizeof...(Ns);
   vec.reserve(vec.size() + num_elements_to_append);
   (vec.insert(vec.end(), std::cbegin(arrs), std::cend(arrs)),...);
}
```

Appending `vertices` and `normals` to an existing `std::vector<float>` becomes:

```
std::vector<float> vec; // your existing vector
// ...
append_to_vector(vec, vertices, normals);
```

For the latter case – i.e., you want to create a new vector out of those two arrays – you can use the following function template, `create_vector`, that in turn calls `append_to_vector`:

```
template<size_t... Ns>
std::vector<float> create_vector(float (&...arrs)[Ns]) {
   std::vector<float> vec; 
   append_to_vector(vec, arrs...);
   return vec;
}
```

Creating a new vector from the arrays `vertices` and `normals` comes down to a single line:

```
auto vec = create_vector(vertices, normals);
```

---

You are not limited to two arrays. You can actually provide an **arbitrary number of arrays** to these function templates thanks to their *variadic* nature, e.g.:

```
auto vec = create_vector(vertices, vertices, normals, vertices, normals);
```

The line above works as you may expect, i.e., it creates a new vector resulting from the concatenation of the elements in `vertices`, `vertices` (again), `normals`, `vertices` and `normals`.

In any case, for each call to `append_to_vector()`, only one reallocation will be performed *at most* because the call to [`std::vector::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) ensures that the memory needed to insert the new elements is available before the insertions.

Answer (score 2):

To insert elements into a `std::vector` of `float`s, you can use [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::vector<float> my_vector;
my_vector.reserve(std::size(vertices) + std::size(normals)); // optional

std::copy(std::begin(vertices), std::end(vertices), std::back_inserter(my_vector));
std::copy(std::begin(normals), std::end(normals), std::back_inserter(my_vector));
```

The order of elements in `my_vector` will be the same as in `vertices` and `normals`.

> Do we need to reserve the memory before inserting the Arrays ?

Technically, no. But reserving memory might help to avoid unnecessary reallocations.

**Edit.**

The [**Notes**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve#Notes) section for `std::vector::reserve` at cppreference reads:

> When inserting a range, the range version of `insert()` is generally preferable as it preserves the correct capacity growth behavior, unlike `reserve()` followed by a series of `push_back()`s.

The recipe in my answer works, but that in **JeJo**'s one should be preferred.

Comment: do we need to reserve the memory before inserting the Arrays ?

Comment: @shomit, no. But reserving memory might help to avoid unnecessary reallocations.